# What is the best way to install ArgoCD as code?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, terraform, continuous-deployment, cicd

Working on getting a full deployment pipeline set up using GitOps and Everything as Code. I, therefore, need to be able to spin everything up and down with a single click (or pretty close to it!). My target is to Terraform a Kubernetes cluster in EKS, then have Argo CD pull containers from docker hub.

In the article "[How To Set Up Argo CD With Terraform To Implement Pure GitOps](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-set-up-argo-cd-with-terraform-to-implement-pure-gitops-d5a1d797926a)", the author advocates using Terraform to install Argo CD.

I have always tried to *avoid* using Terraform for configuration management. In the [Terraform documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/intro/vs/chef-puppet#:%7E:text=Terraform%20is%20not%20a%20configuration%20management%20tool), Hashicorp note that

> Terraform is not a configuration management tool

Is Terraform the best-practice way to perform this action, or is there a better method?

Comment: Is [Kustomize](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/kustomize/) a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

The question seems posed subjectively, and will hence be difficult to answer well, but here goes.

Perhaps what is referred to here by using Terraform via the [k8s](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes) and/or [helm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm) providers to provision the state

> "Terraform is not a configuration management tool"

This means that it is a way to achieve a desired state via a given provider. The article you mention does exactly this, using the k8s provider to provision the state of the argocd cluster.

When would this be a "best" way? When you want to have the *entire* state of the system declared in a single place.

- If you are responsible for *only* ArgoCD, there would be no "best" way, since the [documentation itself](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/installation/) provides a guide for using either Kustomize or Helm.
- If, however, you are responsible for other components, including the infrastructure that ArgoCD requires (network, cluster, security groups, etc), then you would benefit from using Terraform to provision *everything*

Consider the alternative: each part of the system would use its own configuration and provisioning tool meaning lots of context-switching and the need to learn more than one configuration language.

The answer therefore is: The best way to install ArgoCD, or **anything at all** is to first determine the boundaries of the system, then attempt to minimise the tooling necessary to achieve the desired state of that bounded system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) is the way to go.

That is what they use for most of the official Argo CD repositories (e.g., [argoproj/argo-cd](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/tree/master/manifests), [argoproj/argoproj-deployments](https://github.com/argoproj/argoproj-deployments/tree/master/argocd) and [argoproj-labs/argocd-extensions](https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-extensions)).

Note that the they do also have [a Helm chart](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm), which is a perfectly fine way to [install it](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/installation/#helm) too.

For the purposes of configuring Argo CD as code, please also have a look at [Declarative Setup](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/).